# Spell check in Sencha Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, sencha-touch-2, spell-checking

I want to have spell check for a textarea field in my sencha app.

The textarea field is as follows :

```
            {
                xtype:'textareafield',
                id:'txt',
                height:220,                
                autoCorrect:true,


            },
```

I tried using

```
autoCorrect:true
```

which did not help.  Can

```
  spellcheck="false"
```

html property be used?  Is there any deployed WEBSERVICE available so that I can just connect and get the misspelt words? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client side spell check Javascript :

http://www.chrisfinke.com/2011/03/31/announcing-typo-js-client-side-javascript-spellchecking/

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers support the spellcheck attribute, so for example you can have an editable p tag:

```
<p contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">This is a paragraphh. It is editable. Try to change the text.</p>
```

The misspelled word "paragraphh" will be underlined in red.

You can dynamically add the attribute like this using JavaScript:

```
myTextArea.setElementAttribute("spellcheck", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But spellcheck works on desktop browser , the same is not working on mobile devices. Please see my updated question